# Defining composite of piecewise function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, function-and-relation-composition

Let $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x+2, -3\leq x \lt-1 \\
x-1,-1\leq x \lt3
\end{cases}$$

I had to find $f(f(x)$

I defined $f(f(x)$ to be:

$$f(f(x)) = \begin{cases}
f(x)+2, -3\leq f(x) \lt-1 \\
f(x)-1,-1\leq f(x) \lt3
\end{cases}$$

Finally it evaluated to be 
$$f(f(x)) = \begin{cases}
x+1, -3\leq f(x) \lt0 \\
x-2,0\leq f(x) \lt3
\end{cases}$$

But by graphing on a graphing application **Desmos**, I got the following graph:

(**purple** lines indicate $f(f(x))$)

[image]

**Link**: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/knrx71as8b

Isn't the graph wrong? How can $f(f(x))$ return $x+2$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typed it in wrong: you defined $f(x)$ as $x+1$ on the interval $-3\le x\le -1$ in Desmos, where you meant $x+2$. When you fix this typo, the graph is correct.

In your post above, your final evaluation should read
$$f(f(x)) = \begin{cases}
x+1, &\text{if } {-}3\leq x \lt0 \\
x-2, &\text{if }0\leq x \lt3
\end{cases}$$
(you had $f(x)$ in place of $x$ on the right-hand side).

Comment: Thanks man! I am such a fool and I waste time in simple things :(